# how to solve $injector error in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs.i try to create simple page by using some tutorial.One page is for user input html and another one javascript for if else statement.I keep receive error in console as "[$injector:unpr]". index.html

```
<body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
<div class="container">     
                <div class="row price-form-row" ng-if="!addListing">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Min Price</span>
                    <select name="minPrice" id="minPrice" [ng-model]="priceInfo.min" class="form-control">
                      <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                      <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
                      <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
              </select>
                  </div>          
                <span class="input-group-addon">Max Price</span>
                    <select name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" ng-model="priceInfo.max" class="form-control">
                      <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                      <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
                      <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
                     </select>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-4" 
        ng-repeat="crib in cribs | cribsFilter:priceInfo | orderBy: '-id'">          
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i> {{crib.price | currency}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> {{crib.address}} 
                <span class="label label-primary label-sm">{{crib.type}}</span></div>             
 </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/cribsFilter.js"></script>
</html>
```

cribsFiler.js

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .filter('cribsFilter', function() {
    return function(listings, priceInfo) {
    var filtered = [];
    var min = priceInfo.min;
    var max = priceInfo.max;
     angular.forEach(listings, function(listing) {
      if(listing.price >= min && listing.price <= max) {
      filtered.push(listing);
                }
            });
       return filtered;
        }
    });
```

CribsController.js

```
angular
.module('ngCribs')
.controller('cribsController',function($scope, cribsFactory){

$scope.priceInfo ={
    min:0,
    max:1000000
}
$scope.cribs;
cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(data){
    $scope.cribs = data.data;
});
(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
});
```

App.js

```
angular.module('ngCribs',['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: this  error results from the $injector not being able to resolve your dependencies.Some files might be mising here

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `app.js` I can't be certain, but given everything else I can make the following guess:  you should probably add a script tag to reference `CribsController.js` :-)